# How to add a custop page in Azure B2C custom policy flow?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Could I have my custom page displayed before the sign-up page? It will be a required text field with a "Continue" button. After clicking on the "Continue" button the regular sign-up page will be displayed. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with custom policies.

Add a [self-asserted page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile) as the first step of the user journey.